# Continuous Matrix-Valued Functions as Bounded Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

In [Theorem 1.3](https://www.mscand.dk/article/view/12283/10299), the following $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra is considered:

$$A:=\left\{f\in C([0,1],M_2(\mathbb{C})):f(0),\,f(1)\text{ diagonal}\right\}.$$

I want to identify a Hilbert space that these these act on. I want to say that via left multiplication, $g\mapsto fg$, the elements of $A$ are bounded operators on:

$$H:=\left\{f\in L^2([0,1],M_2(\mathbb{C})):f(0),\,f(1)\text{ diagonal}\right\}.$$

Define matrix elements:
$$f(x)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}f_{11}(x) & f_{12}(x)\\ f_{21}(x) & f_{22}(x)\end{array}\right),$$
I want to suggest that each of the $f_{ij}$ are in $L^2([0,1])$ where the norm is got from, e.g.
$$\langle f_{ij},g_{k\ell}\rangle_{L^2([0,1])}=\int_0^1 \overline{f_{ij}(x)}g_{k\ell}(x),$$

and define the inner product on $H$ by:

$$\langle f,g\rangle =\sum_{i,j=1}^2 \langle f_{ij},g_{ij}\rangle_{L^2([0,1])}.$$

Does this actually check out? As in:

> Is the representation of $A$ (via left-multiplication) as bounded operators on $H$ faithful?

Or are there some subtleties and confusions that I am missing out on?

---

Relevant: $A$ is generated by projections
$$p(x)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$$
and
$$q(x)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}x & \sqrt{x(1-x)}\\ \sqrt{x(1-x)} & 1-x\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: If you just want to represent it on a Hilbert space, $L^2([0,1]) \otimes \mathbb{C}^2 \simeq L^2([0,1],\mathbb{C}^2)$ works since $A$ can be identified as a subalgebra of $C([0,1]) \otimes M_2 \simeq C([0,1],M_2)$.

Comment: You are only asking why it is faithful, so I suppose you have checked all the other details (ie that it is a $*$-representation). Consider the function:
$$f_1: [0,1]\mapsto M_2(\Bbb C), \quad x\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
then $(a\cdot f_1)_{ij} = a_{ij}$. If the representation were not faithful there must be some non-zero $a$ so that $a\cdot f_1=0$ in $L^2$, but thats impossible.

Comment: Are you sure that your definition of $H$ actually "works" as a Hilbert space? The elements of $L^2([0,1],M_2)$ are equivalence classes of functions, and as $\{0,1\}$ is a set of measure 0, it doesn't really matter what happens at the end points (in particular, enforcing that the endpoints are diagonal matrices).

Comment: As per my above comment, I think if we wanted a representation of $L^2$ functions from $[0,1]$ to $M_2$ (rather than $\mathbb{C}^2)$, $H$ would just be $L^2([0,1],M_2) \simeq L^2([0,1]) \otimes M_2 \simeq L^2([0,1]) \otimes \mathbb{C}^4$, where the representation boils down to $f \otimes A(g \otimes B) = fg \otimes AB$ (on $L^2([0,1]) \otimes M_2$).

Comment: @PStheman I am not wedded to the Hilbert space above I just want them represented on some Hilbert space. I can see the issue with 0,1 alright. Do you think the Hilbert space with C^2 valued functions works?

Comment: @s.harp thanks but I haven't actually checked anything. PStheman has identified an issue with the space above and has proposed an alternative.

Comment: The Hilbert space $L^2([0,1],\Bbb C^2)=L^2([0,1])\oplus L^2([0,1])$ is the most natural space onto which you can represent $C([0,1], M_2(\Bbb C))$. But you can also represent faithfully into the bounded operators of $L^2([0,1])\otimes M_2(\Bbb C)$ with the scalar product you describe (forget the condition of diagonal matrices).

Comment: @s.harp is that last space the same as $L^2([0,1],M_2(\mathbb{C}))$? So that the functions can be operators by left multiplication?

Comment: @JPMcCarthy yes

Comment: Do you want to write that as an answer? I will upvote and accept. Is it true that in this representation the ranges of $p$ and $q$ intersect trivially ie at zero? This is what I find.

Comment: I muat check in the C^2 representation do they have no trivial intersection. I must check that intersection myself... maybe that was with the incorrect diagonal condition.

Comment: @JPMcCarthy I don't think the authors are requiring that $p$ and $q$ be orthogonal projections in their paper. So I think your concern about the ranges of $p$ and $q$ having trivial intersection (i.e., they are orthogonal projections) is unnecessary (unless there is another reason for it).

Comment: @PStheman projections can have trivial range intersection without being orthogonal. Take for example the the projection onto the $x$ axis and the projection onto $y=x$.

Comment: @PStheman I am interested in any and all $B(H)$ representations, the ranges of $p$ and $q$ zero or not.

Comment: @JPMcCarthy ah you're right, good example! My bad.

Comment: @PStheman I had the same confusion only a few days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with $\pi(A)\subset B(L^2([0,1],\mathbb{C}^2))$ in the end.